# Can someone clone my session Id cookie and login as me?

Tags: authentication, cookies

Because HTTP(s) is stateless, it doesn't remember a username/password combination used to authenticate and assign permissions to a user. I've read that, to overcome this limitation, many websites keep users logged in by means of a cookie, the sessionId cookie if I am correct.

There are 2 questions I am not sure about:

- Is this key used to encrypt data, or that would be a different session key cookie, or none of those ?
- Is it possible if someone copy/paste my session id cookie, to log in seamlessly as myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible if someone copy/paste my session id cookie, to log in
> seamlessly as myself?

It is possible, if you don't protect session cookie:

- If you use HTTP: If you use HTTP, cookie can be read by a man-in-the-middle. To protect it, set attribute "Secure" for such cookie. Then your server will send this cookie only if the request was made via HTTPS and will not send via HTTP. This is important in case you made a mistake in server configuration and allowed not only HTTPS, but also HTTP.
- If there is no protections against XSS: In case of successful XSS attack an attacker script can read the cookie and thus steal it. Then the attacker can use this cookie to impersonate you. To prevent it, you should set "HttpOnly" attribute for session ID cookie.

If the algorithm used to generate session ID is not random enough, the attacker can guess it using some brute-forcing. That's why it is important that session ID has high entropy.

Even if the attacker cannot read your session ID cookie, the attacker can use this cookie implicitly. E.g. if you are logged in in the online banking, the attacker can trick you to submit a request that means transferring money to the attacker. This can happen because browser sends automatically all cookies related to the target domain. Such attack is called [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf). You should implement protection against it. One approach can be setting "SameSite" attribute, but it only protects if you control all subdomains. Some other [CSRF protection](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) techniques can be found on the OWASP website.

Comment: So the servers should not listen at 443 and 80? If I understand you correctly

Comment: WHat I still dont get is this: there are millions of users, If someone creates   some sessionIds, it is not that unlikely that we will match a user one, is it?

Comment: To 443 and 80: It is just common practice that the port 80 is used for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. But is up to you what port for what purpose you use. In my answer I mean that if you configured 443 for HTTPS, you might have forgotten to remove default *listen 80;*. In such case you application will be available not only via HTTPS, but also via HTTP. In such case the attribute "Secure" will prevent sending cookie via HTTP.

Comment: To *"If someone creates some sessionIds"*: Users don't create session IDs. Server creates them. If server uses a random number generator (which uses a proper entropy source), then it is impossible to guess such session ID by brute-forcing. Suppose session ID has 64 bit entropy. 64 bit means a set of numbers from 0 to ~10^19. Suppose the attacker sends 10^9 requests per second to your server with different session IDs and suppose your server can really handle it (which is way too optimistic, if you are not a huge company)...

Comment: ... To try all possible session IDs the attacker will need 10^19 / 10^9 = 10^10 seconds ~= 320 years. Means, if session ID has 64 bit entropy, it is impossible to brute-force it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this key used to encrypt data,

No. It is just to know that multiple requests belong to the same authenticated user session.

> Is it possible if someone copy/paste my session id cookie, to log in seamlessly as myself?

This depends how well the session cookie is protected. If transmission if the cookie is protected by properly using HTTPS and if there are no bugs in the application which allow an attacker to retrieve the key from client or server side, then an attacker needs to actually compromise the client or server to get access to the session cookie - in which case they could do serious harm without even using the session cookie.

Comment: what if someone just takes a picture of it (the session id from the storage dev tab, or from the browser profile) ? thanks a lot for the instructive answer

Comment: Also, I can't understand why this case isn't considered: an attacker trying random strings, maybe of the right length, until it matches a user session id. Doesn't seem that unlikely to me. More if we consider some may have dozens of session Ids enabled..

Comment: @Minsky: *"what if someone just takes a picture of it"* - how would they do this without having access to the computer? *"trying random strings, ... Doesn't seem that unlikely to me"* - assuming a long enough string this it is very unlikely to guess correctly  - practically impossible. Even the fastest computers have a limited performance and if the string is long enough it is impossible to guess.